# Arrow function's lexical scope not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope, arrow-functions

Arrow functions have a bound lexical scope. So in this code `person.person1.sayName()` is supposed to output `HB` but instead it outputs `GOT` (the global scope). Why is this so?

```js
var name = "GOT";
var person = {
   name : "HB",
   sayName : function() { return this.name },
   person1 : {
       name : "WW",
       sayName : () => this.name
    }
};
console.log(person.person1.sayName());
```

Answer (score 4):

Behavior is as expected. Because it's an arrow function, the calling context is inherited from the outer *scope* (the block in which `person` is defined, in which `this` refers to the global object), not from the outer *object* in which `person1` is nested. No calling context is captured when `sayName` is called, and (possibly nested) object initializers do not create a new scope.